# Single WCF REST service with multiple behaviours

Tags: wcf, rest

Is it possible to create a WCF REST 4.0 service which has two endpoints with different behaviours? Specifically I’m looking for one endpoint to use `transferMode=Streamed`, and the other to use `Buffered`.

I’ve started off using the WCF REST Service Application, which seems to be a mix of WCF and ASP MVC routing technologies. I can set transferMode for both endpoints in
`system.serviceModel/standardEndpoints/webHttpEndpoint/standardEndpoint`
but am not having any joy applying additional ones to my routes.

I’m not quite clear where the WCF/MVC separation exists, for example whether the `Global.asax` counts as one WCF endpoint or whether the routes are individual endpoints, and as a result am not sure how to progress.

- Is there a simple `Web.config` change or attribute I can apply to a service to specify different behaviour?
- If not, can I create separate asax files using different behaviours instead of one `Global.asax` file?
- If not, should I create .svc files to map onto my classes as in a normal WCF application?
- If not, will I have to create a second project to define different behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it that way:

```
<services>
  <service name="YourNamespace.YourServiceClass">
    <endpoint address="stream" kind="webHttpEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="webHttpStreamed" contract="YouServiceContract" />
    <endpoint address="buff" kind="webHttpEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="webHttpBuffered" contract="YouServiceContract" />
  </service>
</services>

<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="webHttpStreamed" transferMode="Streamed" />
    <standardEndpoint name="webHttpBuffered" transferMode="Buffered" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Of course, the two endpoints' addresses must not be overlapping.

Comment: Excellent, that’s just the approach I was hoping would be possible :) I have added a service section and a second standardEndpoint; all requests that match the endpoint address use that configuration, and all other requests go through the default unnamed standardEndpoint. 
(The only fly in the ointment is that I must specify an absolute address in order to put https at the front, otherwise it can't tell I have transport security).

Answer (score 2):

Each service route creates a new ServiceHost.  Also, REST Starter Kit is now deprecated, either you should use straight WCF REST 4.0, or you should look into the new WCF Web API stuff at http://wcf.codeplex.com

Comment: Sorry about mentioning starter kit, it is in fact a WCF Rest Service Application.

Comment: Cheers. Do you know of any way that the service hosts can be separately configured? Preferably a lighter way than defining a custom service host.